# Does my database have to reflect my ERD diagram?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, data-modeling

I would like to know if it's mandatory for my database to have the same tables as my ERD diagram?

In my ERD I have 5 tables...: 
[image]

I have a database that only has 2 tables:

- Booking (C_Name, C_Phone, B_Date, S_Time, Ach,)

C_NAME: customer name

C_Phone: customer phone number

B_Date date of booking

S_Time: booking start time

Ach: achieved

- Food(Meal_Name, Meal_Cost)

The customer information is already in the booking table. Is it necessary to create an order table? For the employee table, there is a relationship between other tables, however, this information is not required in my database...

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If the information is not required, then why is it reported within the ERD?

Comment: The ERD and the 2-table database design have some fairly significant differences in how they reflect reality. For example, the DB design does not allow customers who don't (yet) have any bookings. The DB design does not support meal orders or employees.

Comment: If you don't have a CUSTOMER table how will you identify regular customers? If you don't have an ORDERS table how do you know what a customer ate? If you don't have an EMPLOYEES table how will you know who took a booking or waited on a table?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.  An ERD diagram is usually for the *logical data model*.  The most obvious situation is when it contains a many-to-many relationship.  Such a relationship would generally be represented using a junction/association table.

Under other circumstances, you might want to combine different but similar entities into a single table (for instance, to handle one-of relationships).  Or, you may decide to represent some relationships using nested tables or similar mechanisms.  There may be more arcane requirements that call for splitting tables as well.

For your particular model, I would expect one table per entity.  You need additional junction/association tables to handle the employee relationships to `order` and `meal`.